# Good practice for Output parameter in C#

Tags: c#

I have been a C/C++ programmer and new to C#.

I want to return multiple params from a function along with status, so I want to use them as output params. Here is an example.

```
bool SomeFunction(string inStr, out string outStr)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        outStr = AnotherFunction(inStr);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to set value of outStr only based on some condition and not always. However, it does not compile and I have to initialize outStr with some value like below.

```
bool SomeFunction(string inStr, out string outStr)
{
    outStr = string.Empty; // this makes it compile
    if (someCondition)
    {
        outStr = AnotherFunction(inStr);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am looking to not initialize it if some condition fails. In that case, I want to return with an error without initializing. I know it is possible with keyword ref instead of out and I know the difference between ref and out. Is use of ref in such use case a good practice? What are the best practices for output params in a function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Per `out` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) specs _Variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed in a method call. However, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns._ In case of error throwing an exception can help. Or check the return value

Comment: "In that case, I want to return with an error without initializing." Sounds like you should throw an exception then. You don't need to initialize an `out` parameter if the method doesn't complete normally.

Comment: Do you really want `out` parameters? What about returning a tuple type or a own defined type? For tuples, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples.

Comment: return tuple or an object which contain your values. ref/out can affect readability when there are a lot of parameters

Answer (score 6):

The C# community is petty divided on *out* parameters, usually because *a good signature is a signature with as few parameters as possible* and out parameters can always be converted in returned types.

But sometimes they are useful and can still create good looking code.

My best practices:

- Out parameters are always initialized. If the result of the `TryGet` or `TryParse` function is false, then the user should not use the *out* content.
- Attributes come in handy in these cases, if you want to leave the *out* parameter null and you'd like the compiler to help you out: `bool TryGetMessage(string key, [NotNullWhen(true)] out string? message)` (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes))
- If you have more than 1 *out* parameter or if the function is more complex than the one you posted, return an object. It is easier to maintain, to read and to test.
- In the case an object seems too much of a commitment (maybe it would only be used once) you can use a tuple. Don't overdo with them though, readability might suffer.
- `bool` + `out` pattern is universally recognized. If you want to "return an error" with it, maybe this is not what you are looking for (a hard `GetXOrThrow()` might be what you are looking for).
- I wouldn't use `ref` in your case. use ref when you want the value to be modified as a side effect. In this case, `outStr` is definitely a new variable.

Comment: Such a nice answer, but you missed the option of returning a tuple. If that were there I'd upvote.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm not the hugest fan of tuples, but you're right, it deserved to be on the list. I added it.

Comment: Why do you say that readability might suffer with tuples? The syntax seems fairly straightforward and terse to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity They are way more straightforward and easy to use than objects, but their downside is that they suit better when their scope is local. If you need something to pass around, to convert from A to B, used to compose or encapsulated in other objects, you just use objects. Beginners tend to use them as the solution and they end up polluting the code and degrading the readability. Better to treat them as you treat every powerful thing: cautiously :p

Answer (score 5):

Value tuples, or a custom result type, are usually preferred here now. In particular, unlike `out`, this approach is compatible with `async` code. `out` also has a reputation for being poorly understood in general.

Example:

```cs
(bool Success, string Message) SomeFunction(...)
{
    ...
    bool result = ...
    ...
    string msg = ...
    ...
    return (success, msg);
}
```

Note: if `false` would represent an error rather than just a signal: consider throwing an exception instead; this may often (but not always) be preferable.